# How to get widget height in GWT using UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm unable to get the height of the widget in my code

```java
docklayoutpanel.setHeight("1900px");
String height=Integer.toString(docklayoutpanel.getOffsetHeight());
String heightt=height+"px";
System.out.println(heightt);
```

but the o/p is always 0px.

Comment: Could you add code where docklayoutpanel's constructor call is?

Comment: the is too long to be uploaded... :(

Comment: I'm thinking about widget(s) docklayoutpanel contains. Maybe there is the answer for your question.

Comment: i have just taken a Scroll Panel on which i have added  dockLayoutPanel whose center flow panel is having dynamic size and i have to set the height of  center flow panel to docklayoutpanel and in this when i m trying to fetch the height of the flowpanel it is returning zero 0 only...

Comment: Maybe dockLayoutPanel's height is 0px beacause it doesn't contain any widgets. Does it have any?

Comment: it contain 4 flowpanel (north,east, 2-west,center)...

Comment: Okay, but they can also be empty.

Comment: i m unable to get any dimension of any widget(s) in my code even though i am setting their dimension which is perfectly  working..

Comment: no they are not empty they contains several vertical panel and label.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but I had the same problem and it took me quite long to solve it. So to help others here is my solution.
I'm using UIBinder to constuct my views and in the constructor I added a Scheduler.

```
public class MyWidgetImpl extends Composite implements MyWidget {

@UiTemplate("MyWidget.ui.xml")
interface MainViewUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyWidgetImpl> {
}

@UiField(provided = true)
InputPanel inputPanel;

@UiField(provided = true)
ResultPanel resultPanel;

public MyWidgetImpl() {
    inputPanel = ClientFactory.getInputPanel();
    resultPanel = ClientFactory.getResultPanel();

    MainViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MainViewUiBinder.class);
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
        public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
            resize();
        }
    });


    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        public void execute() {
            resize();
        }
    });
}

private void resize() {
    if(Window.getClientHeight() > resultPanel.getCellTree().getAbsoluteTop())
        resultPanel.getScrollPanel().setHeight((Window.getClientHeight() - resultPanel.getCellTree().getAbsoluteTop()) + "px");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It depends where do you call this code. Height will be available after load i.e. you can get you height in `onLoad()` method

Comment: it is being used in the Uibinder.java class which was called by onmoduleload() method

Comment: could you specify the exact method/place where you have this code, it's not enough information to give an advice. BTW if you are speaking about UiBinder interface it has a single method defined createAndBindUi which used to bind the xml presentation with code. Or you use it in another way?

Comment: my code is in the constructor of Uibinder class..... which is being called by the Rootpanel of EntryPoint Class

Comment: it seems not the right place for this code, as I said the best is to place it in the Composite widget's (which is built using this UiBinder) onLoad() method, once the element is attached to the page (then it has size)